# Get time from textview and show exact time in the timepickerdialog

Tags: java, android

Actually, I am frustrated because after so many tries I haven't got any success in getting time from the textview and show it in the TimePickerDialog.
Whenever I click on the layout to get the TimePickerDialog, it always shows 12:00 AM.
I want when I click on this[image] and timepicker will show this time which is on the image.
Here is my code:

```
    public void a(final TextView txv){

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    currentHour=datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    currentMinute=datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
                    if (hour == 0)
                        hour = 12;
                    String strHrsToShow = (String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hour == 0 ? 12 : hour, minute, hourOfDay < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
                    finalTime = strHrsToShow;

                    if (txv.equals(wakeUpTime)) {
                        wakeUpTime.setText(finalTime);
                    }

                    editor.commit();

            }
}, currentHour, currentMinute, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();     
}
```

Comment: how the time is formatted in the text view, show a picture if possible

Comment: I got the time from server in 24 Hr format converted into 12 hr and the show it on the textview

Answer (score 0):

Initialise currentHour, currentMinute to avoid default 12:00 AM.

```
  currentHour = 12;
  currentMinute = 34;

  TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
      new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
... omitted...
    }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);
  timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating object for TimePickerDialog "thetimePickerDialog",
use:

```
timePickerDialog.update(int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour);
```

Which in your case will be :

```
timePickerDialog.update(currentHour,currentMinute);
```